# How to pass multiple folders paths in when a file is created or modified in a folder (properties)

Tags: azure-logic-apps

My logic contain when a file is created or modified in a folder (properties) trigger  my SharePoint path is SharePoint/documents these two folders are same for all SharePoint files later onwards path will changes according to the files for suppose SharePoint/document/abc/calculations/country20230201.xlx here we we don't hardcode the year month and date so next path SharePoint/document/abc/formulas/country20220201

Can you show me the work flow of above one and on actions and trigger how will fill the details can you send these details

Answer (score 0):

You can use folder parameter in *when a file is created or modified (properties only)* trigger to pass multiple folders.

- I have created logic app with trigger as shown below,
  [image]
- Added condition in trigger to check if file is created or modified in folders calculations and formulas.
  Below is the expression written in trigger condition,
  **@or(startsWith(triggerBody()['{Path}'], 'Shared Documents/abc/calculations/'),startsWith(triggerBody()['{Path}'], 'Shared Documents/abc/formulas/'))**
  [image]
  [image]
- If you want to add date dynamically to the file you need to follow below steps.'
- Create a Get file properties action.
- Next get the extension of the file with below expression in compose action.
  last(split(body('Get_file_properties')?'{FilenameWithExtension}'],'.'))
  [image]
- Take another compose action and add current date at the end of file name with below expression,
  concat(concat(body('Get_file_properties')?'{Name}'],formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyyMMdd')),concat('.',outputs('Compose_2')))
- File name before adding date:[image]
  The output of logic app is,
  [image]
- Using copy file action, you can copy file to destination folder.

Reference MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1182747/how-to-pass-two-folder-paths-in-when-a-file-is-cre)

Comment: Thank you vijaya is your solution is suitable if the file is uploaded in first the first path flow is excute successfully in logic but comming to second path i think it will failed for the second path flow insted failed will get pass i think will use condition but how we can implement that case

Comment: last(split(body('Get_file_properties')?'{FilenameWithExtension}'],'.')) is these expression is correct because If I give these expression compose action throws an error like invalid expression

Comment: The expression is correct, and you can see the logic App ran successful also. Once check are u giving it in compose as mentioned in solution.